# Can not send special characters (UTF-8) from JSP to Servlet: question marks displayed

Tags: jsp, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem sending special characters like cyrillic or umlauts from a jsp to a servlet.
I would greatly appreciate your help here.

Here is what I have done:

1. Defined the utf-8 charset in the jsp:

   ```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
       pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    ...

   <div class="authentication">
     <form name="registerForm" action="register" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8">
       <input type="input" name="newUser" size="17"/>
       <input type="submit" value="senden" />
     </form>
   </div>
    ...
   ```
2. Set Tomcat URIEncoding for Connector, in the server.xml

   ```
   <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" ...
   ```
3. Inside the servlet - set the CharacterEncoding to UTF and read request

   ```
   public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{

   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   String username = request.getParameter("newUser");
   System.out.println("encoding: "+request.getCharacterEncoding());

   System.out.println("received: "+username);
   ```
4. Here is what gets displayed when using for example: **Однако**

   ```
   encoding: UTF-8
   received: ??????
   ```

Am I missing something ? I suppose the servlet can not decode the String properly, but I have no idea why is this happening. I've followed all the advises on this topic but had no luck.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything looks fine. Only the `System.out.println()` console also needs to be configured to interpret the byte stream as UTF-8.

If you're sitting in an IDE like Eclipse, then you can do that by setting *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding* to UTF-8. For other environments, you should be more specific about that so that we can tell how to configure it.

Comment: I have already set this. But it does not work for me. Any other settings ?

Comment: @KaushikLele: then you don't have the same question as the OP. Look for a different one or ask a new one. I can't do much else than giving you this link so you can finally understand the world of bytes and characters and can nail down further all on your own: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html